# Is there a word for "the tendency of a community to force others to converse in one's native language"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a word or an expression for the tendency of a specific community to force others to communicate in native language whether conversationally or with shops, hoarding, signage all using native script for usually for its existential promotion.

I have found that the concept behind this word is actualized in many cultures right from Europe to middle east to sub-Asian countries but am not able to find an apt wording for **language imposing tendency**.

Like for example:

> In China, Germans expats are hard pressed to submit to a local translator
>   because of Chinese's ______ tendency.

Comment: It's unclear what you are talking about. ***Whose*** native language are people forced to speak?

Answer (score -1):

In Philadelphia P.A. There's a Fast food spot which forces customers to order the food in English. If they don't order in English, it's no Food for them. THE "WORD"  Philadelphia Residents uses to force others to communicate in native language is, "GENO'S". Everyone from this City Uses the Word in a Racist way when someone isn't speaking the Native Language around them or to them. (They drop the "S" & Call them Geno by Name)  Not everyone agrees with the Restaurant, but it sure did give them National Publicity, Feedback, and Customers.

Comment: Isn't that like the "other" cheesesteak place besides Pat's?